# How to send audio base64 string to server and convert it on java servlet?

Tags: servlets, audio, base64, ibm-watson, speech-to-text

I have a web application that is a chatbot with voice. I'm using IBM Watson and HTML5/JavaScript Client Side and Java Servlet API Server Side. However, when I convert base64 to wav audio file on Java is only noise.

```
function generateBlob(blob) {
  var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  var au = document.createElement("audio");
  var li = document.createElement("li");

  au.controls = true;
  au.src = url;

  li.appendChild(au);
  document.querySelector("#recordingsList").appendChild(li);

  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
  reader.onloadend = function() {
      var base64data = reader.result;
      sendData(base64data);
  }

}

function sendData(data) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open("POST", "speech", true);
  xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  xhr.addEventListener("load", function() {
        if (xhr.status == 200) {
            console.log(xhr.responseText);
        } else {
            console.log(xhr.status);
            console.log(xhr.responseText);
        }
    });

  parameter = "audio=" + data;
  xhr.send(parameter);
}
```

JavaScript blob generation is okay! I can play on HTML. But when I send a post to Java Servlet is not working. After convert it from Base64 to File, it is only noise.

```java
String audio = req.getParameter("audio");
        System.out.println(audio);
        byte[] byteArray = Base64.getMimeDecoder().decode(audio.split("base64,")[1]);
        File tempFile = File.createTempFile("speech-", ".wav", null);
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(tempFile);
        fos.write(byteArray);
        fos.close();

        try {
            AudioInputStream ais = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(tempFile.getAbsoluteFile());
            Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
            clip.open(ais);
            clip.start();
        } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException | LineUnavailableException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        IamOptions options = new IamOptions.Builder()
                .apiKey("<api_key>")
                .build();

        SpeechToText service = new SpeechToText(options);

        RecognizeOptions recOptions = new RecognizeOptions.Builder()
                .audio(tempFile)
                .contentType(HttpMediaType.AUDIO_WAV)
                .build();

        SpeechRecognitionResults transcript = service.recognize(recOptions).execute().getResult();
        System.out.println(transcript);
```

Anyone can help me, please?

Comment: Encoding to base64 is a waste of bandwidth, you can just send binary data. Also, you should use streaming instead of sending files as a while, that will make things more responsive.

Comment: Hey Nikolay! Tks for commenting.
Do you have an example to help me, please?